# Lazy loading images from drawables in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, lazy-loading

I'm trying to lazy load my images in my drawabale folder into a grid view. but it seems that setImageDrawable is slowing the scrolling down.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView anImageView;
    if(convertView == null){
        anImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        anImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        anImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    } else {
        anImageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    anImageView.setImageDrawable(...);

    return anImageView;
}
```

can anyone help?

Comment: are you setting the drawable with an image that is already loaded? Or are you bringing in each image from your /res/ folder at runtime?  Or are you loading each image from the internet one at a time?                    I assume you've done the profiling to know that setImageDrawable is the slow portion and it's not actually somewhere else?

Comment: i'm bringing each image from res folder at runtime.All the images are in the drawable folder .no network calls. Should i create an async task that creates the drawables and pass the drawables in to the gridviewadapater? no, no profiling. I've just read online that other people had the same problem with loading a bunch of images to a gridview using setImageDrawable inside the getView method

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating an imageloader async task and set the drawbale of the image view onpostexecute. Just in case anyone else ran into the problem. The scrolling is now smooth

Comment: Hey i have a question for you,how are you handling the memory consumption?

Comment: Memory consumption was an issue i was having too. Fortunately the images were pretty small (i.e. 126 x 126 px). I made sure to resize them before handing them off to the grid fragment (70 x 70). Other than that, i'd probably recommend some third party lazy loader. Loading them through async task looked horrible on older phones.

Comment: most of the third party lazy loader are very complex-ed and  are based mainly on images from internet,i tried modifying them,but didn't work :(